# Inheritance and converting objects

Tags: c#, oop

I have `SalesMan` class which is inherited from `User` class and also implements `ISalesMan` interface.

```
public class SalesMan : User, ISalesMan
{
 ...
}
```

I need to convert `User` objects into `SalesMan` objects. I understand that direct casting from `User` type of objects into `SalesMan` type is not possible. How should I do the converting? I'm thinking two different ways:

1. Creating constructor for `SalesMan` class that takes `User` parameter and initializes a new `SalesMan` object based on the given `User`.
2. Creating new method for the `SalesMan` class that takes `User` as a parameter and returns a new `SalesMan` object based on the given `User` parameter.

...or is there an even smarter way to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor described in Option 1 is what I would expect to find if I were poking around an unfamiliar API.

They can be boring beasts to write though, and you may forget to update them when adding new fields to the User class. So (if performance considerations allow), consider writing an "intelligent" constructor using reflection, [along the lines of this example](http://www.johnsadventures.com/archives/2006/07/an_intelligent_copy_constructor_in_c_usi/).

On the issue of constructors versus factory methods, the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Development/dp/0321545613) offers the following advice:

> - DO prefer constructors to factories,    because they are
>     generally more    usable, consistent,
>     and convenient    then specialized
>     construction    mechanisms.
> - CONSIDER using a factory if you need    more control than can be
>     provided by    constructors over the
>     creation of the    instances.
> - DO use a factory where a developer    might not know which type to
>     construct, such as when coding
>     against a base type or interface.
> - CONSIDER using a factory if having a    named method is the only way to
>     make    the operation
>     self-explanatory.

Comment: The "intelligent" copy constructor described in the article only works for value type fields. Additionally, if many instances must be constructed like this Reflection may be too slow.

Comment: I wouldn't call option 1 a copy constructor. They are usually of the form: MyClass(MyClass o)

This would be called a conversion constructor in C++

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is the tidiest and most intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create a SalesMan object from a User object then either of the options you describe would work.

But I think you need to ask yourself what you are trying to do. When/why does a User become a SalesMan? Are you trying to change the bahaviour of an existing object? Do behaviours change regularly in your system?

Depending on your needs, you might consider using the Strategy or Template Method patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I use option 1. upgrade constructor or conversion constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The answers you've already received are more than sufficient. However, I noticed you mentioned that casting wasn't possible. If you have some sort of reason to employ casts, you can *make it possible* by overloading an operator.

```
public static explicit operator SalesMan(User user)
{
    // Your logic to create a new SalesMan using data from user.
}
```

Determining which solution is *smarter* would require more information than was provided in your original post. However, I tend to air on the sides of completeness and versatility, and would considering doing both.

```
public class SalesMan
{
    public SalesMan(User user)
    {
        // Your logic to create a new SalesMan using data from user.
    }

    public static explicit operator SalesMan(User user)
    {
        return new SalesMan(user);
    }
}
```

And Ian's right. General rule of thumb is use a factory only when you have a functional requirement that can't be met with a constructor, or the constraints of the language start to get in your way. For example, needing two different constructors with an identical signature.